# Defining click behavior on prototype of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a table that when a `tr` is clicked in the tbody a function is called that writes something to the console.  I would like this object to be something like this

```
function FancyTable(table) {
    this.rows = $(table).find('tbody tr');
    //need to add the behavior in the event handler somewhere here
    this.rows.click = function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
FancyTable.prototype.getData = function (tr) {
    var row = $(tr);
    console.log(row.text());
}
var fancyTable = new FancyTable('#table1');
//Need to keep this behavior
$('#table1 tbody tr').click(function () {
    console.log('this needs to be attached to the FancyTable object');
});
```

I would like for all of the click behavior to be encapsulated within the FancyTable object instead of having to add the click event handler in the page.  What's a basic method for doing something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8DGXP/)

Happy Holidays :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` member is a method that takes a callback function, you don't assign a new function to `click` to bind an event.

Call `click` with the event handler as parameter, just as you did when you did bind the event in the page:

```
this.rows.click(function () {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/8DGXP/2/

Comment: How would this change if I had to process something like getting the text of the table cell that was clicked? I made an attempt, but failed. http://jsfiddle.net/8DGXP/3/

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Then you would bind the click event to each cell rather than each row. That way `this` in the function is the cell that was clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/8DGXP/4/